# Need to determine which files are called for execution in AIX server directory

Tags: shell, scripting, aix

I have a set of execution files like .sh scripts and other execution files in a AIX Server directory. In these, all the files were automatically called by 3rd party Application and this will be automatically executed and completes. Now the task is to figure out, which are the files are really executing & which are all just sitting idle in the directory. Because we have many files of duplicated name in sub-directories too. Is there any way to automate for echo the filenames which are really called / working in production? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try command `ls -lutr /dir/`: the recently used files will be at the end of the list.

Comment: When I execute this command, it shows the time(Oct 24 2016) . Is that file last executed time? Because when I try to run ls -l it lists below(File created time -Nov 15 2005)

$ ls -l 
-rw-r--r--    1 arsmo6   c_pjdepr      10685 Nov 15 2005  c5742459a.c
-rw-r--r--    1 arsmo6   c_pjdepr       1779 Nov 16 2005  c5742459a.h

$ls -lutr
-rw-r--r--    1 arsmo6   c_pjdepr      10685 Oct 24 2016  c5742459a.c
-rw-r--r--    1 arsmo6   c_pjdepr       1779 Oct 24 2016  c5742459a.h

Comment: Seems like these files haven't been used recently. Kindly read `man ls` to find out what these options mean.

Comment: Yes, I have read, Thanks for the idea

  -u
            Uses the time of the last access, instead of the time of the last modification, for either sorting (when used with the -t flag) or for displaying (when
            used with the -l flag). This flag has no effect if it is not used with either the -t or -l flag, or both.
       -x